# "Newtons laws applied to a train of 3 cars"

Tags: classical-mechanics

A train consisting of three cars of mass 'm' each is pulled with force 'F' by a locomotive in a straight, horizontal line. Assuming there is no friction, find the force on each car.

How would I answer this question?

Comment: The subject matter of this question is better suited to Physics.SE, but in its current form it'd probably be closed under their homework policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole train experiences some acceleration $A$, so $F = 3 m A$.  Each car, of mass $m$ experiences the same acceleration, so $F_{{\rm car}} = m A = (1/3) F$.

Thought experiment:  if you put a (very stiff) spring in each linkage between cars and between the lead car and the loc. to measure the force applied at the linkage, what would you see?